Trying to repeat Group Header in the right side column in a multi-column report
I've created street listing report in Crystal Reports 2020 that is multi-columned. The street name appears fine in the Group Header section but only in the left column. It doesn't repeat or appear in the right column and since it is multi-column you are not allowed to place fields in that area. If a street name continues from the left column into the right column I would like to display the street name in the group header section on the right column as well. For example, if "Elm St" appears in the left column I would like the group header section in the right column to display "Elm St Con't".
I've tried creating formula fields and different ways of adding a new group header section and suppressing, etc but there seems no way to repeat group header fields in the right column.Street Name on left and where it should repeat on the right.

You probably need to turn the 'Format Groups with multiple columns' property:
enter image description here

Thanks but I have that set. It only works on the left column. It looks fine if a new street just happens to begin with the 1st record in the right column but not when the same street continues from the left colunm over to the right one.  I'm really starting to think it cannot be done. I'm at the point where I'm adding another detail section below and trying to create formula fields but so far have been unsuccessful. Thank you for your input, regardless.
